# Hierarchical data in R- How do I sum over subsets, while maintaing the tree?

Tags: r, data-analysis

Probably, I haven't defined the problem very well. I don't seem to understand what R is returning out of `sapply`. I have a large dataframe of hierarchical data. About half the columns are factors and half are numerical. I want to get a new dataframe that contains some of the factors, and sums over the numerical columns, but I want the sums to remain separated by factor levels.

For instance, from the sample data below, I'd like to make a dataframe with the state, district, branch the same, but sum the data for orders of the same type but with different colours. I'm thinking that iterative use of `sapply` will do it, but I can't seem to get it to work.

sample data:

```
state district branch   order   colour  number  cost    amount
CA   central newtown    shoes   black   6   25.50  127.40
CA   central newtown    shoes   brown   3   32.12   75.40
CA   central newtown    gloves  blue    15  12.20  157.42
CA   central newtown    gloves  black   9   8.70    65.37
CA  central columbus    shoes   black   12  30.75   316.99
CA  central columbus    shoes   brown   1   40.98    45.00
CA  central columbus    gloves  blue    47  11.78   498.32
CA  central columbus    gloves  black   23  7.60    135.50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another job for `aggregate`.  Calling your data frame `dat`:

```
aggregate(cbind(cost, amount) ~ state+district+branch+order, data=dat, FUN=sum)

##   state district   branch  order  cost amount
## 1    CA  central columbus gloves 19.38 633.82
## 2    CA  central  newtown gloves 20.90 222.79
## 3    CA  central columbus  shoes 71.73 361.99
## 4    CA  central  newtown  shoes 57.62 202.80
```

On the left side of the ~, `cbind` is used to indicate that we want each column separately.  If `cost + amount` were specified, it would mean the sum here because these are numeric.  On the right side of the ~, we have factors, so the + means that we are aggregating by each level of each factor.

Comment: Well, it looked good... but I'm getting an error when I use it as written: `cannot coerce class "formula" into a data.frame`. The formula seems to be due to ~, but it's used differently in different packages. I don't have any packages loaded, just plain vanilla R. I've tried using by=list(state,district,branch,order), but that's not working either.

Answer (score 1):

i've always found sql the most intuitive for aggregation  :)

```
    library(sqldf)

    # write a full aggregation command, grouping by your specified columns
    x <- sqldf( "select state, district, branch, order, sum( cost ) as sumcost, sum(amount) as sumamount from yourdata group by state, district, branch, order" )

    # print your result
    x
```

here's [an explanation of aggregate() and tapply()](http://www.screenr.com/JQS8) and here's the same [explanation of sql within r for aggregation](http://www.screenr.com/zmd8)